# Nomality of blow-ups of higher dimensional rational singularities

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

A theorem (Theorem 8.1) of Lipman [Lipman1969](http://www.numdam.org/article/PMIHES_1969__36__195_0.pdf) shows that the blow-up of a rational singularity on a normal surface is still normal. Does anyone know under what (extra) condition Lipman's results can be generalized to higher dimensions? To be more precise, let $X$ be a normal variety with only rational singularities and $Z$ be an irreducible subvariety of $X$ with codimension $\geq 3$. Is the blow-up $\mathrm{Bl}_ZX$ normal? If not, under what extra condition, $\mathrm{Bl}_ZX$ will be normal?

Comment: maybe at least you need some good condition on $Z$? Otherwise even if $X$ is smooth the blowup might not be normal.

Comment: I guess so. Do you have an example that the blow-up is not normal? Or do you have an example of good conditions? Thank you!

Comment: Do you really need to blowup a subvariety?  Instead of blowing up a radical ideal, I believe that blowing up the integral closure of a high power of that ideal will be normal (ie, it is the normalization of the original blowup).

Comment: Hi Karl, thank you! I am interested in the relation between $\mathrm{mult}_ZX$ and the self-intersection of the exceptional divisor $E$ on the blow-up when $Z$ is simply a closed point. I am not sure whether $\mathrm{mult}_xX=E^{\mathrm{\dim X}}$ if we consider the normalized blow-up.